# How do I parse the array index numbers rather than the content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do I actually check the index number rather than its contents against the condition? I'm trying to remove every other index if the index number itself %2 == 0. Also, if I don't have it look at the index numbers but instead string contents, is there a way to get the numeric value of the string character?

```
function removeEveryOther(arr){
    zvar arr = Array.from(arr);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]%2){
            var myArr = arr[i];
            console.log(myArr);
        }
    }
}

removeEveryOther();
```

Comment: Replace `arr[i] % 2` with `i % 2`? You could also just move two steps every iteration. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `Number(arr[i])` to get the numeric value of the string.

Comment: What is `zvar`? Is that a typo for `var`?

Comment: Oh! Yes, that was a typo. Must have done it just before submitting.

Comment: Funny thing is I needed to step away. I came back and looked at it and smacked myself for not using i instead of arr[i]. It was so obvious. Came back here to announce that but you all corrected me already. Thank you all very much for your input!

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just compare i against 2, so i % 2, since i is the index number? I think that is what you are asking?

Comment: agreed.  The way its written in the original post compares the value not the iterator.  Also this would be a good use case for 'reduce'..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce